# Cálculo de Estimativa de Tempo

Tags: algoritmo

Estou fazendo uma calculadora para cálculo de Tempo para qualquer distância em meu site, porém a minha dúvida está no algoritmo de execução.

A fórmula é a seguinte:

`tempo previsto` = `tempo real` **x** `distância prevista` **/** `distância do tempo real elevada a 1.07`.

Só que quando efetuo esse cálculo na calculadora vem um resultado quebrado que eu não sei como vou transformar em um algoritmo que retorne horas, minutos e segundos. A fonte é o seguinte link: http://www.penoasfalto.com.br/calculos.html

1. Previsão de tempo para qualquer distância:

Comment: Você está usando JAVASCRIPT ou qual linguagem de programação?

Comment: Jquery, uma condição de cálculo é tempo real = 1h, distância prevista = 12, distância atual = 11 km, tempo estimado de :1,097573872, este é o resultado na calculadora, agora no site o resultado é: 1h 05m 5q seg.

Comment: Converta os valores para unidades comuns, faça o cálculo e depois converta em horas novamente. Sugiro segundos (que é a menor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/axgucsy6/

```
function calcularTempoTotalPrevisto( horas, minutos, segundos, distanciaPrevista, distanciaPercorrida ) {
  var horasTotalOcorrido = horas + ( (minutos * 60 + segundos) / 3600 );

  var horasTotalPrevisto = Math.pow( ( distanciaPrevista / distanciaPercorrida ), 1.07 ) * horasTotalOcorrido;

  var horasPrevisto = Math.floor( horasTotalPrevisto );
  var segundosPrevisto = ( horasTotalPrevisto - horasPrevisto ) * 3600;
  var minutosPrevisto = Math.floor( segundosPrevisto / 60 );
  segundosPrevisto = Math.round( segundosPrevisto - minutosPrevisto * 60 );

  return { "h": horasPrevisto, "m": minutosPrevisto, "s": segundosPrevisto }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado realizei um cálculo parecido e pelo jeito, funciona só falta a implementação em jquery, Valeu Obrigado!!!